# OpenCV 2.3 RC Python SVM: TypeError: <unknown> is not a numpy array

Tags: python, opencv2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to use the new cv2 SVM (Support Vector Machine) Python binding in OpenCV 2.3 RC.  I compiled OpenCV from [source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.3/) under Ubuntu 10.04 and as soon as I execute this function:

```
svm = cv2.SVM(training_data, responses)
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: <unknown> is not a numpy array
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or how to fix this?

Here is the full function I am using to train the SVM. The variables self.positive_samples and self.negative_samples are Python lists of SURF feature vectors (64 elements long).  The variable self.classes is a Python list of 1's and -1's indicating the class a sample belongs to.

```
def init_classifier(self):
    
    n_positive_samples = len(self.positive_samples)
    n_negative_samples = len(self.negative_samples)
    
    n_samples = n_positive_samples + n_negative_samples
            
    training_data = cv.CreateMat(n_samples, 64, cv.CV_32FC1)
    responses = cv.CreateMat(n_samples, 1, cv.CV_32FC1)
    
    for i in range(n_positive_samples):
        cv.Set2D(responses, i, 0, self.classes[i])
        for j in range(64):        
            cv.Set2D(training_data, i, j, self.positive_samples[i][j])
            
    for i in range(n_positive_samples, n_samples):
        i_negative = i - n_positive_samples
        cv.Set2D(responses, i, 0, self.classes[i_negative])
        for j in range(64):        
            cv.Set2D(training_data, i, j, self.negative_samples[i_negative][j])

    svm = cv2.SVM(training_data, responses)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10403/opencv-2.3-rc-python-svm:-typeerror:-%3Cunknown%3E-is-not-a-numpy-array/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2011-06-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK, it only took me about 5 hours of trial and error to finally figure this out.  Turns out the SVM class requires the training data to be of type numpy.float32.  Since my training data was in regular Python arrays, I had to convert them like this:

```
training_data = np.array(python_training_data, dtype=np.float32)
responses = np.array(python_responses, dtype=np.float32)
```

Now all is well.

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2011-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1